# How to use /AlwaysOutline command in ghostscript pdf processing?

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, postscript

I have PDF with different fonts embedded. One of them is color emoji font. For some unknown reason the font with emoji crashes my printing software. The only way I found is to convert all fonts to outlines using gs `-dNoOutputFonts` parameters. Unfortunately file became very big and quite slow to print.

Then I found that there is AlwaysOutline parameter that should convert to outline only fonts I want.

But the [example provided there](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#vectordevices-nooutputfonts) has no effect for me:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -c "<< /AlwaysOutline [/Calibri (Comic Sans) cvn] >> setdistillerparams" -f input.pdf
```

No matter how I tried, I can't make any particulat font to be outlined.

### This is what I tried

For the testing purpose I took pdf with these fonts:

```
# extracted with pdffonts version 22.02.0
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object    ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CIGRAP+NotoSans                      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    526  0
PGJSDK+DejaVuSans                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    534  0
FFCMLR+NotoSansSymbols2              CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    538  0
VMLNYD+NotoSans-Italic               CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    542  0
ZBMDWE+NotoSans-Bold                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    546  0
```

And this is partial output of pdfalyze utility:

```
...
╭────────────── ─ ─                                                                                            │
│ 526. Font /CIGRAP (Type0)                                                                                │                                                                                            │
╰─────────────── ─ ─
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│                sub_type │ /Type0           │
│               base_font │ /CIGRAP+NotoSans │
│                   flags │ None             │
│            bounding_box │ None             │
│      /Length properties │ None             │
│ total advertised length │ None             │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘

...
```

Then I used this command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -c "<< /AlwaysOutline [/CIGRAP+NotoSans] >> setdistillerparams" -f input.pdf
```

I've tried to use different font names with the suggested command: `/CIGRAP+NotoSans`, `/NotoSans`,  `/CIGRAP`, `CIGRAP+NotoSans cvn`, `CIGRAP cvn`, `(CIGRAP+NotoSans) cvn`, ...

Nothing helped. No errors. There are still all same fonts in output PDF.

**Does is work for anyone?**

**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Those are all CIDFonts, not Fonts. However I see no reason why it shouldn't work. I'd suggest you open a bug report, and attach a (small!) example file which doesn't work along with your command line.

Comment: As I suspected, it is the fact that these are CIDFonts. The code removes any subset prefix, so you don't need to specify that, but it cannot reliably detect a composed font with a CMap name. The font is being sent as NotoSans-Identity-H because the CIDFont name is composed with the CMap name to generate the font name. You need to do: -c"<</AlwaysOutline [/NotoSans-Identity-H]" -f in order to specify the font to be outlined. NotoSans-Italic will have to become NotoSans-Italic-Identity-H and so on.

Comment: I've updated the documentation to be clearer that you should not specify the subset prefix, but that for CIDFonts you do need to specify the composed name; that is the name of the CIDFont composed with the name of the CMap (which may **not** always be Identity-H or Identity-V !) It will be a few hours before the change gets reflected online though.

Comment: @KenS I did not make it work. Still nothing. Here is my 5Mb file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4i5ap12o8m0xxiuwxxpv9/stackoverflow_q_77257782.pdf?rlkey=v47y6ltack5516ucv84kqoxiq&dl=0 This uncompressed PDF so maybe you can just look at its content. I see some `/CmapName` commands... What is the correct command to make NotoSans font outlined? How to get that name to use in command line.

And BTW there still no changes in docs. 18 hours passed.

Comment: **Which** NotoSans ? There are 4 members of the NotoSans font family in there; NotoSans, NotoSans-Bold, NotoSans-Italic and NotoSansSymbols2. All the fonts in the file are CIDFonts, and all of them are using an Identity-H CMap. So you need [/FontName-Identity-H]. Also surely its the Emojis you want converted to outlines?

Comment: Well I can't see why this doesn't work, and a 252 page file with 7 fonts, lots of text and  large images (which crashes Acrobat 9!) is much too complicated to try and debug. If you can find a simpler file then I suggest you open a bug report.

Comment: And finally.... Using the current release (10.02.0) and this command line : -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o /temp/out2.pdf -c "<</AlwaysOutline [/NotoSans-Bold-Identity-H]>>setdistillerparams" -f /temp/stackoverflow_q_77257782.pdf produces a PDF file where the NotoSans-Bold CIDFont is no longer present. Similarly using NotoSans-Identity-H.

Comment: @KenS Thank you! I had older ghostscript v9.55. Compiling new version solved my problems. I still had insteresting behavior: in order to remove Emoji font I have to use font name without `Identity-H` suffix. Just name itself was enough. Would you like to create an answer here?

Comment: You should be using the current version if for no other reason than the fact that there are known security exploits for earlier versions. I'd have to debug the code to see what's up with the Emoji font, but it sounds like it is not a CIDFont, otherwise it would include the CMap name. As I said, the file is really too unwieldy to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @KenS I've solved my problem. Let me summarize the results:

1. Try latest version of ghostscript. In my case it was 9.55 Linux version that did not work properly. Compiling current v10.02.0 (2023-09-13) helped.
2. Some types of fonts require not just font name to be declared, but both fontname and its CMap (or encoding?) like `Identity-H`. Like this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf \
   -c "<</AlwaysOutline [/FontName-Identity-H]>> setdistillerparams" \
   -f in.pdf
```

3. If your software shows font name with prefix like `/QXGYNG+CairoFont-0-0`, use it without prefix: `/CairoFont-0-0`.